# Java linq equivalent for getting property in list with highest value

Tags: java

Im having a list of results, `ArrayList<PlacedObject> result`:

```
for(PlacedObject po : result){

     float[] results = new float[3];

     Location.distanceBetween(lastlocation.getLatitude()
     ,lastlocation.getLongitude()
     ,Double.parseDouble(po.lat)
     ,Double.parseDouble(po.lng) ,
     results);

     po.distance = results[0];
}
```

After the `po.distance` is set, i would like to sort my list by the `distance` property. In c# i would use linq, but is there any similar solution in java?

Thanks

---

Current solution:

```
Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<PlacedObject>(){
public int  compare(PlacedObject s1, PlacedObject s2) {
    return (int) (s1.distance - s2.distance);
}
});
```

Comment: Would it be an alternative to keep the list sorted at all time? Then you might be intersted in a `SortedSet<T>`. This way you do not have to manually apply sorting afterwards. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is accomplished with the implementation of a `Comparator<T>` class:

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method (such as Collections.sort or Arrays.sort) to allow precise control over the sort order.

It could be applied to your list with [Collections.sort(list, comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). Basically you implement your own Comparator and pass it to the method.

An implementation could for instance use an anonymous inner class:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<PlacedObject>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(PlacedObject po1, PlacedObject po2) {
        return Double.valueOf(po1.distance).compareTo(po2.distance);
    }
});
```

If you are only intersted in the maximum, as your headline indicates, there is also [Collections.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) which is applied in the identical way.

Comment: Thanks, please check my update. Thats what i came up with. Does it look ok or should i change to this?

Comment: @Johan I don't see any difference, it comforts to the specification for the return values of `compare` I think you are okay with your implementation.